# AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayBackAndRecord shows on the car's bluetooth speaker that call is initiated on the self number

Tags: ios, swift, text-to-speech, avaudiosession

I am converting `text to speech` and playing it on the Car's `bluetooth speaker`. But when it plays on the car's bluetooth , the car's bluetooth screen show that it initiated the call on the self number. If the iPhone do not contains the SIM card it starts showing the timer. iPhone has no sign of calling being initiated.

**I am using following code to play the text in car's bluetooth :**

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try? audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth,.allowBluetoothA2DP])
    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("Error in the session")
    }

let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
synth.speak(utterance)                            
synth.continueSpeaking()
```

Comment: This is normal behaviour when you use the `.allowBluetooth` option. Invoking Siri will do the same thing. If you use only `.allowBluetoothA2DP` then you won't see a call but the audio will only be heard if the car entertainment system is playing Bluetooth streaming

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please confirm that how it can be checked that car entertainment system is playing Bluetooth streaming after connecting the iPhone to the car's bluetooth system? As after connecting with bluetooth, the other music apps plays the song but the call feature is not shown.

Comment: I tried using only .allowBluetoothA2DP but the audio cannot be heard in bluetooth speakers

Comment: Was the audio device set to play streaming audio from your device?  Unlike a handsfree, A2DP won't pre-empt a different audio selection.

Comment: I just connected the phone with car's bluetooth and Started playing the app.